# What is an efficient way of loop through rows of a polars LazyFrame?

Tags: dataframe, rust, row, apply, rust-polars

I have a large Parquet file with just a few columns, and I'd like apply a function to each row of the Paruqet file. What is an efficient way of doing that? By efficient, I mean 2 things.

1. The code runs fast.
2. The code doesn't load the while file into memory but rather process it a few rows at a time.

Comment: Efficient and row wise access do not match well in polars. We have columnar memory.

Maybe you can ask a more conrete question and ask how you can do achieve that goal efficient.

Comment: The [parquet](https://crates.io/crates/parquet) crate does allow row-wise access to Parquet files. I have been using it in the past and is wondering whether I can totally replace it with polars.